# Phonegap app closes when another activity is started. Why?

Tags: android, cordova

I have a javascript interface set on my DroidGap class,

```
mc = new MyClass(this, appView);
appView.addJavascriptInterface(mc, "MyCls");
```

From which i'm starting the media player

```
  public void playAudio(String audioFile){
      copyFileToDir(audioFile);
      File dest = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC + "/" + audioFile + ".mp3");
      Uri r = Uri.fromFile(dest);         
      Intent viewMediaIntent = new Intent();   
      viewMediaIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);                                 
      viewMediaIntent.setDataAndType(r, "audio/*");   
      viewMediaIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);          
      Intent i = Intent.createChooser(viewMediaIntent, "Play Music");
        mGap.startActivity(i);

  }
```

But when i do that, when i press back, my app is not running anymore and i get sent to the home screen.
I tried  setting the keepRunning to true but didn't help much.

```
super.setBooleanProperty("keepRunning", true);
```

How can I keep it running even when I start another Activity?

**Update**

Now it gets weirder. The activity does not get destroyed on a nexus 7 running 4.2, on a HTC desire/Htc Bravo running 2.2 but it fails on my galaxy s3 running 4.1.2. Any ideas on how to find out why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue was self inflicted. There is an option on `Settings -> Developer Options -> Apps` called `do not keep activities`. And it destroys every activity as soon as the user leaves it. So once I unticked that lovely checkbox, my problem was solved.